# Explain this notation: $\overline{g(x)}$

Tags: notation

In my analysis homework, I have this expression:

$$
(\cdot | \cdot): \quad C[a,b] \times C[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{K}, \; (f,g) \mapsto (f |g) := \int_a^b f(x) \overline{g(x)} \;dx
$$

Any idea what $\overline{g(x)}$ stands for?

**EDIT**

$\mathbb{K}$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: What's $\Bbb K$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [complex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate).

If $z = a+ib$, then $\overline{z} = a-ib.$

Comment: It is a **hermitian** dot product (sesqulinear form), useful when $f$ or $g$ are complex valued. Furthermore, if you take $f=g$, it gives the integral of the square of the modulus.